# Create zip files in ruby by running unix commands, no gems please

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, command-line, zip

The script is working perfectly fine. The only issue I am facing is path. Once the zip file is created. If I unzip its. its having a complete path of the file like:--

```
/name_the_file/Users/user_name/projects/project_name/public/system/files/10/original/*
```

I just want to make it

```
name_of_the_file/*
```

---

```
 desc "Create Zip file"
  task :create_zip => :environment do
  directory_path = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/system/files/10/original"
  bundle_filename="#{directory_path}/"+ "name_of_file.zip"
  filenames = "#{directory_path}/*" 
  %x{ cd #{directory_path}}
  %x{  zip -r  #{bundle_filename}  #{filenames}}
end
```

PS:- I want to create zip files. No tar, gzip etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:--

```
  %x{  zip -r -j  #{bundle_filename}  #{filenames}}
```

Normally this would result in a zip containing three "subdirs":

```
a/
+ file1

b/
+ file2

c/
+ file3
```

With -j, you get:

```
./
+ file1
+ file2
+ file3
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supplying the entire directory path with each filename. Since you have already changed to that directory, you don't need to do that.

In other words, if you change your `filenames` variable to:

```
filenames = "*"
```

It should work as you intend.

Comment: . Its not working. I am not able to change my directory from projectname  Check edit part

Comment: It may be spawning two distinct subshells. Try `%x{ cd #{directory_path}; pwd }`

Comment: %x{  zip -r -j  #{bundle_filename}  #{filenames}} worked. -j is the option not to save the path..